# How to mount storage to app service using Az powershell module

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am running the following command

```
az webapp config storage-account add -g appxxx-dfpg-dev2-web-eastus2 --name appxxx-dfpg-dev2-web-eastus2-backoffice-apsvc --storage-type AzureBlob --share-name central-imports-dev4 --access-key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==   -a appxxxdfpgg --mount-path /central-imports -i CentralImports
```

And it works fine.
How I can achieve the same result using Az powershell module, I guess I need to use Az.Websites module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`New-AzWebAppAzureStoragePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/New-AzWebAppAzureStoragePath?view=azps-3.8.0) command, use it to create an Azure Storage path, then use `Set-AzWebApp` to update the web app.

**Sample:**

```
$storagePath1 = New-AzWebAppAzureStoragePath -Name "RemoteStorageAccount1" -AccountName "myaccount.files.core.windows.net" -Type AzureFiles -ShareName "someShareName" -AccessKey "some access key"
-MountPath "C:\myFolderInsideTheContainerWebApp" 

$storagePath2 = New-AzWebAppAzureStoragePath -Name "RemoteStorageAccount2" -AccountName "myaccount2.files.core.windows.net" -Type AzureFiles -ShareName "someShareName2" -AccessKey "some access key 2"
-MountPath "C:\myFolderInsideTheContainerWebApp2" 

Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroup myresourcegroup -Name myapp -AzureStoragePath $storagepath1, $storagePath2
```